# In vscode, how to format text with /n linebreak

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting

This may be the dumbest question.

When I read log on elastic, I get a bunch of text with "\n" linebreak

I usually use vscode as a text editor.

When I copy/paste a log message in vscode, is there a way to ask vscode to format it and replace the "\n" with an actual linebreak?

Answer (score 4):

If you are in an editor I think you are going to have to do this:

Find: `\n`  the regex option should **not** be selected

Replace:  Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the replace input field

You should get find hits on all the `\n` literal texts in your log, replace all to see the result with actual newlines replacing all those literal `\n`'s.  Demo:

[image: literal \n replacement with newlines]